# how to restrict a page to only a specified ip range in php

Tags: php, php4

im looking for a way to restrict my administration page to only my own ip range

concider my ip range is 215.67.*.*

so in php i will begin with this :

```
$myip = "215.67.*.*";
$myip = explode(".", $my_ip);

$userip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR") ; 
$userip = explode(".", $userip);

if ($myip[0] == $userip[0] AND $myip[1] == $userip[1]  ) {
    //Contunue admin
}
```

is there any better and more professional way to do it ?

Comment: See the comment section here: http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
function in_ip_range($ip_one, $ip_two=false){
    if($ip_two===false){
        if($ip_one==$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']){
            $ip=true;
        }else{
            $ip=false;
        }
    }else{
        if(ip2long($ip_one)<=ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) && ip2long($ip_two)>=ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])){
            $ip=true;
        }else{
            $ip=false;
        }
    }
    return $ip;
}
//usage
echo in_ip_range('192.168.0.0','192.168.1.254'); 
?>
```

Taken from http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php#81030